# d3 selectAll().data() just returns data in first element. why

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get the data in all the matching element using d3. I have following code

```
d3.selectAll('svg').selectAll('.line').data()
```

what i expect is that it should return data in all the matching element. but it just return data in first matching element.

if i just do

```
d3.selectAll('svg').selectAll('.line')
```

this shows that it has 2 group element and its *data* property contains the data.

if i just do `var line = d3.selectAll('svg').selectAll('.line'); line[0].data()`it gives me error. as line[0] become a DOM element without any property

how to get data in all matching selection or am i not clear on how to use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `d3`, but I'm pretty sure the `.selectAll()` returns some sort of list of elements, like an `array`. Check the documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour as the spec on [`selection.data(values)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) reads:

> If values is not specified, then this method returns the array of data
>   for the first group in the selection.

That explains why you only get the data bound to the first group.

To access data bound to *all* groups returned by your selection you could use:

```
d3.selectAll('svg').selectAll('.line').each(function(d) {
    // Within this function d is this group's data.
    // Iterate, accumulate, do whatever you like at this point.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see your code, therefore I will show you a working one:

```
// scene setup
// we generate 3 SVG tags inside the page <body> 
var $svg;
for (var svg = 0; svg < 3; svg++) {
   $svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr({
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      id: "svg_" + svg
   });
}

// multiple selection + data
// consider the array of colors as data
var array_of_colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "khaki", "gray", "green"];
d3.selectAll("svg").selectAll("line.dash").data(array_of_colors).enter()
        .append("svg:line").attr({
            x1: function(d){return(50 + Math.random() * 50);},// random coordinates
            y1: function(d){return(50 + Math.random() * 50);},// random coordinates
            x2: 150,
            y2: 140,
            "stroke-width": 2,
            stroke: function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                return (d);
            }
        }).classed({
            "dash": true
        });
```

The code produces 6 lines (as size of data array) in each SVG element:

[image]

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your effort..the answer rovided by 'altocumulus' explains the real issue.